# Removing self executing anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

I am using an anonymous function and a Slider() function. I need all the same functionality in only one function. The anonymous function which I am using is should be removed. The below code should come into one function.

This is what I  tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/QNZDX/5/

```
$(function() {
        //FadeIn/FadeOut Image on Set Time Interval on Slide
        timer=setInterval(Slider, mainInterval);
        var div=$('<div id="paging_inner"></div>');
        for(i=0;i<maximages;i++)
        {
            div.append($('<a id="page_'+(i+1)+'" data-index="'+(i+1)+'"><span></span></a>'));
        }
        $('#paging').append(div);

        $('#paging a').on('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          clearInterval(timer);
          prevIndex=$(this).attr('data-index')-1;
          $('#paging div a span').stop(1,1);
          Slider();
          timer=setInterval(Slider, mainInterval);
        });

    });

    function Slider() {
        $('#imageSlide').fadeOut("slow", function() {
            if (prevIndex >= maximages) prevIndex = 0;

            $("#panel").fadeIn("slow").css('background', '#000');

            var title = $xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + prevIndex + ")").find("title").text();
            $("#title").text(title).fadeIn("slow");

            var imgurl = $xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + prevIndex + ")").find("url").text();
            $(this).attr('src', imgurl).fadeIn("slow");

            var desc = $xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + prevIndex + ")").find("desc").text();
            $("#desc").text(desc).fadeIn("slow");
            $('#paging a span')
            .removeClass('active').css('display','block');
            $('#paging a#page_'+(prevIndex+1)+' span')
            .addClass('active')
            .slideUp(mainInterval);
            prevIndex++;

        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Just `+` instead of those `slideXML +=`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but the function you pass to domReady doesn't have to be anonymous. `$(function iHaveAName() { //FadeIn/FadeOut ... });`

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

> It's more than an anonymous function - it's a self-calling anonymous
>   function

But in this case it is not necessary at all,

this will work same as previous

```
//FadeIn/FadeOut Image on Set Time Interval on Slide
timer = setInterval(Slider, mainInterval);
var div = $('<div id="paging_inner"></div>');
for (i = 0; i < maximages; i++) {
    div.append($('<a id="page_' + (i + 1) + '" data-index="' + (i + 1) + '"><span></span></a>'));
}
$('#paging').append(div);

$('#paging a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    clearInterval(timer);
    prevIndex = $(this).attr('data-index') - 1;
    $('#paging div a span').stop(1, 1);
    Slider();
    timer = setInterval(Slider, mainInterval);
});

function Slider() {
    $('#imageSlide').fadeOut("slow", function() {
        if (prevIndex >= maximages) prevIndex = 0;

        $("#panel").fadeIn("slow").css('background', '#000');

        var title = $xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + prevIndex + ")").find("title").text();
        $("#title").text(title).fadeIn("slow");

        var imgurl = $xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + prevIndex + ")").find("url").text();
        $(this).attr('src', imgurl).fadeIn("slow");

        var desc = $xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + prevIndex + ")").find("desc").text();
        $("#desc").text(desc).fadeIn("slow");
        $('#paging a span').removeClass('active').css('display', 'block');
        $('#paging a#page_' + (prevIndex + 1) + ' span').addClass('active').slideUp(mainInterval);
        prevIndex++;

    });
}
```

> Anything declared with "var" inside the function is private to that
>   function and cannot be accessed from outside it. That's actually the
>   main reason for using self-calling anonymous functions: to provide a
>   local scope where you can set up functions and variable without
>   cluttering the global namespace.

Look at the [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QNZDX/6/)

Comment: Can you edit it in Jsfiddle its not working I tried your code

Comment: @ui1 why you suppose to combine? As far as i think, this one is already optimal.